# How to convert my json to .CSV File Without library in Android?

Tags: android, json

Here is My json file that i want to convert into a .CSV file

```
"data": [
    [
      "Date",
      "MM Name",
      "MM Mobile",
      "Service Name",
      "Service Type",
      "Sale",
      "Txn Count",
      "Reversal Sale",
      "Reversal Txn Count",
      "Net Sale",
      "Net Txn Count",
      "Total Incentive"
    ],
    [
      "2020-01-02",
      "XYZ",
      "782531",
      "DSC Individual",
      "DEVICE",
      "9404.00",
      "1",
      904,
      1,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ]
  ],
```

Most of the answer i found uses some library which are deprecated.Please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
var csv = data.map( row => row.join(',') ).join('\n')
```

I used this code on a website. If you print this string in a file .csv, you can open it with excel and it works pretty well

Answer (score 0):

The shell tool jq is of great help when dealing with JSON-data."jq" has a filter, @csv, for converting an array to a CSV string.
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/once-upon-time-formats-kopal-gupta/ You can refer to my blog in this I have clearly explained how u can achieve your desired CSV.